# SQL Pivot or other solution for multiple field values to return a single object from sub table values

Tags: sql, t-sql

Firstly; just to get it out of the way :) I have been given a few tables with work with and they are unchangeable.

The main table is called Content with a single row=1 piece of content. All the first level dynamic fields added to it (via a dynamicly built content type in its own table) are in a sub table called FieldValues which has multiple fields for specific value types depending on the field itself: FieldStringValue, FieldDecimalValue, FieldLongValue, FieldDateValue, FieldBoolValue. Identification mapping is handled via the ReferenceName field which is a unique name added when building the content type itself.

The want is to return a single row Content 'object' with the sub table rows as fields with their respective values.

So far i have this SQL which does what i want for string values only:

```
SELECT C.Id,C.ContentTypeId , Fields.*
FROM Contents AS C
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT ReferenceName,FieldStringValue
        FROM FieldValues
        WHERE ReferenceName IN (
            'recipename','recipenamehtml','url','introblurb','linkcopy','serves','makes','prep','cook','imgsetland','imgsetport'
        )
        AND ContentId = C.Id
    ) AS FieldList
    PIVOT (
        MAX(FieldStringValue)
        FOR ReferenceName IN (
            recipename, recipenamehtml, url, introblurb, linkcopy, serves, makes, prep, cook, imgsetland, imgsetport
        )
    ) AS PIV
) AS Fields
WHERE C.Id = 930 AND C.ContentTypeId = 2
```

But i am a little stumped on how to 'add in' checks for FieldDecimalValue for example - am i going about it the wrong way? For example how do i add in fields with referencenames of "energy, calories, carbs, protein, dietryfibre, fat, satfat, sugar" with values from FieldDecimalValue instead of FieldStringValue?

I'd like to keep table scanning to a single pass which is why i tried to go about this way by using a pivot on a single query - at least the execution plan looked ok to me :)

EDIT: Server is SQL Server 2012, any t-sql specific tricks are ok. Additionally i realise i could just repeat the OUTER APPLY section with FieldDecimalValue but the execution plan shows 2 table scans to get the data which is what id like to find a way around (if possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work - can't believe i didn't think of it before :)

Only 'problem' is that all result fields will be returned as one data type unless i manually convert back again. But it seems to result in a single table scan.

Still open to better suggestions on the query if anyone has them.

```
SELECT C.Id,C.ContentTypeId , Fields.*
FROM Contents AS C
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT ReferenceName,CASE
                WHEN ReferenceName IN ('energy', 'calories', 'carbs', 'protein', 'dietryfibre', 'fat', 'satfat', 'sugar') THEN CAST(FieldDecimalValue AS nvarchar(MAX))
                ELSE FieldStringValue
            END AS FSV
        FROM FieldValues
        WHERE ReferenceName IN (
            'recipename','recipenamehtml','url','introblurb','linkcopy','serves','makes','prep','cook','imgsetland','imgsetport'
            , 'energy', 'calories', 'carbs', 'protein', 'dietryfibre', 'fat', 'satfat', 'sugar'
        )
        AND ContentId = C.Id
    ) AS FieldList
    PIVOT (
        MAX(FSV)
        FOR ReferenceName IN (
            recipename, recipenamehtml, url, introblurb, linkcopy, serves, makes, prep, cook, imgsetland, imgsetport
            , energy, calories, carbs, protein, dietryfibre, fat, satfat, sugar
        )
    ) AS PIV
) AS Fields
WHERE C.Id = 930 AND C.ContentTypeId = 2
```